# Django, LDAP and custom permissions/groups

Tags: python, django, django-auth-ldap

I'm using LDAP to authenticate users in my django app. This works fine. But I have one problem: In my settings.py I have the following entry:

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_great": "cn=admins,ou=application,ou=myorg,c=de",
}
```

After logging in, `user.is_great` becomes `True`. Using this in the template after the login works fine too: `{% if user.is_great %}` results in `True`. That's what I'm expecting. **But** after changing the the page of my App, this value disappears.
When examining the database, I don't see the `is_great` permission anywhere.

Any idea how to fix that and have the ldap group/is_great permission bound to that session?

Comment: It looks like the `is_great` flag will be set on the user model, not as a permission. Do you have a custom user model that has an `is_great` field?

Comment: nope I use the default model. Can I extend the User model without rewriting it completely by myself?

Comment: The docs for creating a custom user model are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). I believe that if you subclass `AbstractUser`, then you can simply add your additional fields. I haven't used custom user models before, so can't offer any more advice. Good luck!